# Use scriplet in include tag

Tags: jsp

I want to perform some action like

```
<%    Locale locale = request.getLocale();    %>
<%@include file="/layouts/common/modal_body.<%="_"+locale%>jsp"%>
```

Basically i have a variable in `locale` in scriplet and want to use it to point to some jsp of that locale but dont know how to achieve it any idea pls.
is scriplet in another scriplet allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@include file` is called static include, It is like an inline inclusion i.e., the contents of the file will be included at translation phase (Remember `#include` of `C`). It can not have dynamic file name.

For that you have to use `<jsp:include page=”fileName” />`

The Syntax is

```
<jsp:include page="{relativeURL | <%= expression %>}">
```

So,

```
<%    Locale locale = request.getLocale();    
      String myPage = "/layouts/common/modal_body._"+locale+".jsp" ;
%>
<jsp:include page="<%= myPage %>">
```